# Not able to create azure alert for metrics

Tags: azure, alert, monitoring, metrics, azure-application-gateway

Registered **Microsoft.AlertsManagement**

[image]

But still not able to assign alert to metrics

[image]

I'm using Azure ChinaCloud

Comment: Do yo have rights to create alerts and view metrics?

Comment: @SamCogan just answered downstairs

Answer (score 0):

Just received the answer from Azure ChinaCloud supporter.

[image]